# Create a new colum in every iteration

Tags: r

In a for loop

How is it possible to create a new column in every iteration like this for loop:

```
for (i 1:2) {
df1$col[i] <- sapply(df1$text, function(fragment) {
  result <- read_html(paste0("<html>", fragment, "</html>")) %>%
  html_node(xpath = my_xpath) %>%
  html_text()
  if(is.na(result)) 0 else trimws(result)
}, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}
```

create two new columns col1 and col2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. But in order to specify a new column by index, you have to use the column index (`[,i]`). To create them by name, you put the name in double brackets (`[["name"]]`).

So, just change your first line to:

```
df1[,i] <- sapply(d...
```

Or if you want to name them `col1` and `col2`, use:

```
df[[paste("col",i,sep="")]] <- sapply(d...
```